# All combinations/cases of equality of 3 variables

Tags: inequality, permutations, combinations

I have three `integer` variables like:

```
c0, c1, c2
```

I don't have the focus and have a difficult time determining all the possible cases of their equality:

```
if c1 == c0 && c2 == c0 {
    // ...
} else if c1 != c0 && c2 != c0 && c1 != c2 {
    // ...
} else if c1 != c0 && c2 != c0 && c1 == c2 {
    // ...
} else if c1 == c0 && c2 != c0 {
    // ...
} else if ... ?
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Consider $c_0 ? c_1$, $c_1 ? c_2$, $c_0 ? c_2$, each of the question marks can be $=$ or $\ne$ ($2^3$ cases), but $(=,=,\ne)$, $(=,\ne,=)$, $(\ne,=,=)$ are illegal so we're left with $5$ possibilities.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin That's a good logic =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are either all equal (one possibility), or two are equal and one isn't (three possibilities), or none are equal (one possibility). This gives us five unique possibilities in total:

```
if c0 == c1 && c1 == c2 {
    // ...
} else if c0 == c1 && c1 != c2 {
    // ...
} else if c1 == c2 && c0 != c1 {
    // ...
} else if c0 == c2 && c1 != c2 {
    // ...
}
```

And now use else to account for the last possibility of none of them being equal:

```
else {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. All three are equal, that is, $c_0 = c_1 = c_2$
2. Only two of them are equal, that is, $c_i = c_j \neq c_k$ where $\{i,j,k\} = \{0,1,2\}$. This case has three possibilities without repetition, since when you choose $k$, the pair $(i,j)$ and $(j,i)$ corresponds to the same thing.
3. None of them are equal to one another.

You can program it as follows :

```
if c0 == c1 && c1 == c2 : 
  //
elif c0 == c1 && c1 != c2 : 
  // ..   
elif c1 == c2 && c2 != c3 : 
  // ..
elif c2 == c3 && c3 != c1 : 
  // ..    
else : 
  // ..
```

(the else part corresponds to the last possibility, when $c0 \ != c1 \land c1 \ != c2 \land c2 \ != c3$)

Comment: You have too many variables! I think you meant {i, j, k} = {0, 1, 2}

Comment: How could I miss the $0$-indexing? Oh right, it's MSE and not SO ;)

Comment: @charlesh I wish I could accept more than one answer :( Sorry! I just accepted the answer which was posted sooner! Thanks for your clear explanation =)

Comment: That's perfectly alright, OP. 

@DerekO You seem to have worked on some interesting projects. I am curious about a couple of things. Do you mind if I drop you a few questions on your personal email or maybe through your homepage/contact?

Comment: @charlesh Sure thing! I'm a bit busy with work but happy to answer any questions you have when I get the chance :)